# Can you call submit() on another site from a local script

Tags: javascript, submit

There is a site that I have a repetitive task of submitting / clicking. I have automated this via a macro however it takes control of the UI of my laptop. Is there a way to write a script that would automate the click/submit in the background?

This is the "code" in the site.

```
<div class="lContainer" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('lId').value
  ='56e9bc31303070f211f625f0';document.getElementById('gallForm').submit();">
<div class="lCount">2668</div>
<div class="l">Submit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tampermonkey userscript manager

https://www.google.co.uk/#q=tampermonkey